# RxJava Single.toCompletable() seems to break the Single somehow

Tags: android, rx-java2

**Note**: It turns out the `toCompletable()` was not at fault but instead it was the calling code. The calling code was such that changing this method was making it work (or not work).

---

I have the following method. It returns a Single. It works. The code inside is executed such that the remoteDataSource Single downloads the data and the code in `doOnSuccess` runs and I can breakpoint in there.

However, if I convert it to a completable as in the second example it stops working. The data is not downloaded and the code inside `doOnSuccess` never runs.

I want to convert it to a Completable in this method because the method that calls this method doesn't need the data, just the success/error result.

Any idea why this is happening?

It says in the documentation

> Returns a {@link Completable} that discards result of the {@link Single}
>        and calls {@code onComplete} when this source {@link Single} calls
>        {@code onSuccess}. Error terminal event is propagated.

But I thought it meant that it would discard things for the calling method, not the current method. By converting to Completable even the remoteDataSource Single won't download the data.

**Working:**

```
override fun downloadSomethingList(): Single<List<Something>> {
    return remoteDataSource.getSomethingList(getHash(SOMETHING_HASH))
      .doOnSuccess { it: Map<String, List<Something>>
        saveHash(SOMETHING_HASH, it.keys.first())
        localDataSource.replaceSomethingList(it.values.first())
      }.map {
          it.values.first()
      }
}
```

**Broken:**

```
override fun downloadSomethingList(): Completable {
    return remoteDataSource.getSomethingList(getHash(SOMETHING_HASH))
        .doOnSuccess { it: Map<String, List<Something>>
          saveHash(SOMETHING_HASH, it.keys.first())
          localDataSource.replaceSomethingList(it.values.first())
        }.toCompletable()
}
```

---

Update:

Ok here is my calling method. Yes it's a little complicated. Maybe something in there is causing the problem.

```
fun downloadData(): Completable {
    ...
    return repository.downloadThing1()
        .flatMap { downloadedThing1 ->
            ...
            repository.downloadThing2().toSingle()
        }
        .flatMap {
            repository.getThing2()
        }.flatMap { thing2 ->
            ...
            repository.saveThing1(thing1).toSingle()
        }
        .flatMap {
            if ("some condition") {
                repository.downloadThing3()
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing4())
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing5())
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing6()).toSingle()
            } else {
                Completable.complete().toSingle()
            }
        }.toCompletable()
        .doOnComplete {
            ...
        }
}
```

---

Update 2:

If I use the following calling code it works! **So the lesson learned is that the calling code can definitely break the upstream**. More specifically I think it was all the `toSingle()` calls. Instead I discovered `flatMapCompletable` which seems to be designed for this purpose.

Since there was nothing actually wrong in the original code in the question I've had to award the points to Sanf0rd for showing this to be the case.

```
fun downloadData(): Completable {
    ...
    return repository.downloadThing1()
        .flatMapCompletable { downloadedThing1 ->
            ...
            repository.downloadThing2()
        }.andThen(repository.getThing2())
        .flatMapCompletable { thing2 ->
            ...
            repository.saveThing1(thing1)
            if ("some condition") {
                repository.downloadThing3()
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing4())
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing5())
                    .andThen(repository.downloadThing6())
            } else {
                Completable.complete()
            }
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: where is your calling code?

Comment: the calling code is a bit complicated. do you think the calling code can change the upstream stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a little piece of code to try it and it's working:

```
val single = Single.create<Int> { emitter ->  emitter.onSuccess(5) }
val completable = single.map { it * 2 }.doOnSuccess { Log.d("MyTag", "$it")}.toCompletable()

completable.subscribe()
```

Make sure that you are calling subscribe with the Single and Completable version.

Comment: i'm just cleaning up the calling code. a bit messy after all my experiments. then I'll post it. I think it must be the way I'm calling it.

Comment: I'm just doing more testing but it seems the calling code is at fault. And maybe by making the method in my question a Single it was such that the calling code was "compatible".

Comment: so if that's the case I guess your answer is correct in that it's not the "toCompletable" that's breaking it.